# Asp.net RegularExpressionValidator c# double with comma and dot

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm working on a simple application form that needs a simple RegularExpressionValidator for c# double.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ErrorMessage="Only numbers"
                                ControlToValidate="textbox" 
                                ValidationExpression="[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*"
                                CssClass="redtext"
                                ValidationGroup="save"/>
```

I need the validation to allow numbers as well as "," and "."

I've tried a couple of different validation expressions but no one allows the specified characters.

Examples of text that should be allowed:

```
1
50000000
0,5
0,05
0.05
1.3232
9.9999
0.09
```

Any other characters should not be allowed

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^\d+[\.\,]\d+$
```

or

```
^(?=.*\d)\d*[\.\,]\d*$
```

**EDIT:**

You can try this regex:

```
^(\d*\.?\d+|\d*(,\d*)*(\,\d+)?)$
```

Comment: Do you have a good source where one might learn more of how to build the expressions? Would be greak to understand it better. I've look some at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx

Comment: @GeorgeNorberg:- You can follow this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: The two expressions you suggested didn't work for me. Are there some other regex that might work

Comment: @GeorgeNorberg:- Can you provide a sample input which you are trying to parse?

Comment: Sure, I'll add some examples to the questions

Comment: @GeorgeNorberg:- Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: I tried it on https://regex101.com/ and it seems to be working with "." but in my asp.net application page on validation of a asp.net textbox control it still triggers the validation on "." and ",".

Comment: @GeorgeNorberg:- For .Net regex you can use: http://regexstorm.net/tester And it is working fine on the regex. Can you specify the case where it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Try below one

```
   1.  ^[0-9]{1,2}([,.]{1}[0-9]{1,2})?$
   2.  \d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,2}
```